# Getting error in finding sum of digits of large inputs?

Tags: c++

```
long long n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int s=0;
while(n > 0){
    s = s + n%10;
    n = n/10;
}
printf("%d",s);
```

//gives wrong ans for input: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to write the best possible question. In this case, it would be helpful for us to know what were you expecting it to give, and what it gives instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the wrong output because such gigantic values couldn't be hold by the type specified for the variable `n` (i.e. `long long`).

The `long long` range can only hold from (0 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807) whereas `unsigned long long` could (0 to +18,446,744,073,709,551,615), but in this case, you've inputted:

```
9999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Which clearly overflows.

---

In such cases, you may use the [Boost Library](https://www.boost.org/) and use wide-integer types such as `uint512_t`, `uint1024_t` to hold values like:

```
6989373397903475430537974005643661187443125371384456079195486281758221158058129839557943213043044175415113790933927760188672456
```